# Drupal and Twitter Bootstrap, spans in views

Tags: drupal, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-views, responsive-design

Let's say that I want a Drupal View to display un unknown amount of "items". I would like to display 4 items per row (in the width of the page).

I would normally use a `row-fluid` container and have 4 `span3` items in it.

Now how would I achieve that using Drupal Views module so that this would get repeated if I have 8 elements (2 rows of 4) or 9 elements (2 rows of 4 + 1 row with only 1 element), etc.

If this is not feasible with the Views module, what approach would you suggest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews module!  You'll see it is quite easy.